# Foreign keys and unique index on the same table

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sites_routing` (
`origin_site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`destination_site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`distance_meters` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'walking',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I want to create two foreign keys for columns origin_site_id and destination_site_id and than another unique index on 3 columns: origin_site_id, destination_site_id  and type. If I'm doing that mysql becomes really slow on reading and writing to the table and I can see in the error log stuff like:

*sites_routing contains 4 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of ns 4 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 3 defined in the MySQL*

Still, if I try to drop the fks and the indexs and recreate the fks when the unique key exists, mysql allows me to create only one fk using the unique key as index but for the other one it automatically creates another index.

What's the best way to go here?

Comment: Can you reset the table following [this advice](http://www.percona.com/blog/2011/11/29/innodb-vs-mysql-index-counts/), with `ALTER TABLE sites_routing ENGINE=Innodb` command?

Comment: Currently I managed to make it work somehow by allow mysql to use the unique key for one fk and create index for the second fk. Still, it's not working too fast.